# how to get java version in batch and echo something if empty out or not

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, batch-file, java

this is a batch to detect java, but always set ok

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (echo %%i)
IF %%i == "" (echo fail) else (echo ok)
```

How do I modify this script so that if java is not installed on the system (32 or 64 bits or both) "echo FAIL" and if it is installed (32 or 64 bits or both) "echo OK"

PD: If it doesn't work properly with the above, I would also accept responses with this command (or any other):

```
wmic product where "name like '%%java%%' AND NOT Name like '%%java auto%%'"
```

PD: [I have found a batch](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/FROSADO/355314691ce94c0df9bd/raw/3fca1ab9c46d641fabb3e29be9d1896222157f94/check_java.cmd) that does just what I want, but it is long and complicated, and I have not been able to simplify it. I make it available to give solution ideas

Comment: Do you actually need the version or are you simply checking if it exists and is in the path?

Comment: I just want to know if java is installed (32 or 64 bits). I am not interested in the version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case you describe, you should use the `where` command coupled with checking the exit code (ERRORLEVEL) to see if the program exists and is in the path.

Example:

```
    @echo off
    where java 2>NUL
    if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (call :JavaFound) else (call :NoJava)
    goto :EOF

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    :JavaFound
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    Echo Java found.. checking version...
    goto :EOF

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    :NoJava
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    Echo Java not found, you need to install it.
    :: install java here?
    goto :EOF
```

Comment: can you modify your answer in a "for do if else" loop? something like https://superuser.com/a/1526975/886205

Comment: For loop makes no sense unless you are trying to scrape STDOUT or STDERR.  Sample modified.  If you want to loop on the version after determining that it exists.. that is more code.

Comment: OK.. ok.. I looked at your sample link.. can help.

Comment: ohh. thanks again for the improvement

Comment: You are welcome. :)  Also, note that this method requires Java to be in the application path.. for instance (I write java in addition to other languages) it is NOT in my path but I good and well have several instances of it on my machine.  The windows registry is a good place to look but sucks because it varies from version to version.